# Append suffix in L20n

Tags: html, l20n

I want to localize a web application with L20n and in the UI a word is often followed by a colon. E.g.: `Foo:`.

The following approach works but it has the drawback that an extra tag must be defined for each word followed by a colon.

```
In the .l20n-File:
    <foo "Foo">
    <fooCol "{{foo}}:">

In the .html-File:
    <p data-l10n-id="fooCol"></p>
```

I tried the following to avoid these extra tags, but that approach does not work.

```
In the.l20n-File:
    <colon "{{$var}}:">

In the .html-File:
    <p data-l10n-id="colon" data-l10n-args='{"var": "{{foo}}"}'></p>
```

Is there an elegant way in L20n to add a suffix to a word?

Answer (score 2):

I missed the obvious solution:

```
<p><span data-l10n-id="foo"></span>:</p>
```